# How to calculate the T(N) for this primes finder algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

This algorithm find all prime numbers below N

```js
var f = function(n){
    var primes = [2];  //1
    var flag; //1
    for(var i=3; i<n; i+=2){  // ( from 3 to n-1 ) / 2
        flag = true; //1
        var startI = 0; // 1
        for(var y=primes[startI]; y<=Math.sqrt(i); y=primes[++startI]){ // ???
            if(i%y === 0) // 1
                flag = false; // 1
        }
        if(flag) // 1
            primes.push(i); // 1
    }
    return primes; // 1
}
```

So far my analysis is done till the first loop, I'm not sure how to handle the second sum ( the one that is using `primes.length` and `Math.sqrt` ).

> T(n) = 1 + 1 + sum( ( 1+ 1+ ??weird sum???) , from i = 3 to n -1) / 2 + 1 + 1

I understand how to analyze till the second nested loop, I suspect that is around log(N) or something like that, but I would like to know the exact number of iterations..

Questions:

- How can I handle that kind of loop that is using arrays in memory to iterate ?
- If not possible to get the exact number, how can I get a good approximation ?

Any help is appreciated (links to similar cases, books, etc ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The inner loop iterates over the array of all primes below `sqrt(i)`.
So you have to calculate the number of elements in that array. In the case of an array of primes, you have to use approximations for `π(i)`, the number of primes below `i`.

You can approximate them by `x/ln(x)` or (much better) by [`li(x)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function). More [details here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).

For analysis the `x/ln(x)` would be easier.

In total you get (assuming `n = 2k+1`)

```
T(n) = T(n-2) + O(sqrt(n)/( (1/2)⋅ln(n) )) = O( Σi = 1,...,k 2⋅sqrt(2⋅i+1)/ln(2⋅i+1) )
```

You get the recursive formula from the inner for loop, that iterates over the array of primes lower than `sqrt(n)` (approximated by `sqrt(n)/( (1/2)⋅ln(n) )`), and the work you have to do to come this far, represented by `T(n-2)`.

Maybe you can simplify this more. I don't want to take the fun from you :)

Hint: Maybe you can use an integral to get an approximation of the sum. But I think there is no "nice" way to write it down.

If you forget about the `1/ln(i)`-part, you can see
`T(n) ∈ o(n3/2)` and `T(n) ∈ ω(n)`. Maybe you can do better.

As @vib mentioned, you can get a tighter upper bound `O(n3/2/ln(n))`. But notice that `sqrt(n)/ln(n)` is only an approximation for the number of primes lower than `sqrt(n)`. Thus you get better bounds with better approximations. Since this approximations do not provide the exact value of `π(n)`, we **cannot** say that this algorithm runs in `Θ(n3/2/ln(n))`.

Comment: Obviously the sum is upper bounded by n * sqrt(n) / ln (n)   (its largest term), and is O(n^{3/2} / ln n). By restricting the sum to the range n/a <= i <= n for some fixed a>1 you get that T(n) is Omega( n^{3/2} / ln n). So you get a tight asymptotic for T(n)

Comment: Thanks, I'll add this to my answer. The problem I have with complexities like `O(n^{3/2} / ln n)` is, that it is hard to compare to others, since you dividing by something. I tried to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand why you did T(n-2) + sqrt(n)/0.5*ln(n), can you elaborate more on that please ?

Comment: @rahpuser I added an explanation and I corrected the sum a little bit. The sum was not correct, but in big-O it changes nothing.

Comment: @AbcAeffchen Can you please provide me with a book or website where I could learn more about it ?

Comment: @rahpuser To be honest: I never read a book about complexity-theory. Maybe you can learn something from other questions here at SO. Maybe you can find some good reads on the website's of some professors, but I only know some works in german and they are not official published.